# Override a function that's not in a class

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a function that I want to override from another file without changing the original. How would I do that?

Here's an example of my function.

```
def url_for(path_or_uri, lang=None):
    if isinstance(path_or_uri, unicode):
        path_or_uri = path_or_uri.encode('utf-8')
    current_path = request.httprequest.path
    if isinstance(current_path, unicode):
        current_path = current_path.encode('utf-8')
    location = path_or_uri.strip()
    force_lang = lang is not None
    url = urlparse.urlparse(location)

    if request and not url.netloc and not url.scheme and (url.path or force_lang):
        location = urlparse.urljoin(current_path, location)

        lang = lang or request.context.get('lang')
        langs = [lg[0] for lg in request.website.get_languages()]

        if (len(langs) > 1 or force_lang) and is_multilang_url(location, langs):
            ps = location.split('/')
            if ps[1] in langs:
                # Replace the language only if we explicitly provide a language to url_for
                if force_lang:
                    ps[1] = lang
                # Remove the default language unless it's explicitly provided
                elif ps[1] == request.website.default_lang_code:
                    ps.pop(1)
            # Insert the context language or the provided language
            elif lang != request.website.default_lang_code or force_lang:
                ps.insert(1, lang)
            location = '/'.join(ps)

    return location.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: This really needs a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, this method is located outside any class

Comment: Then what are you trying to do? Give an actual example of what you want to do, not just the code you have right now.

Comment: What do you mean by override a function?

Comment: @MorganThrapp, this is the real method. No more to show. I just need to override it in another file

Comment: RIght, I don't know what you mean by override. What are you trying to achieve by overriding.

Comment: @RafaelCardoso, to replace it with another one. I can't touch original

Comment: Just define a new function with the same name.

Comment: If I have this method in a class, i would just inherit it and overwrite it. But there is no class for the current one, so I have the problem

Comment: @MorganThrapp, if i do what you advice - i won't overwrite it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you're trying to do.

If you want to change the definition of a function in another module after importing it, you can just reassign it the same way you would reassign any variable.

Here's an example:

`foo.py`

```
def foo():
    print('Goodbye, World')


def foo_caller():
    foo()
```

`main.py`

```
import foo


def new_foo(var):
    print('Hello, World!')


foo.foo = new_foo

foo.foo()
foo.foo_caller()
```

If you put these in files that are named as specified and run `main.py`, you'll see that it uses `new_foo` in place of foo, even for internal function calls in that module.

Comment: You got me right, Morgan. What should I do if i have the input to my methods? I mean if foo has the input variable "var"?

Comment: @keywoker You can assign any function you want. Just put that parameter in the function you define.

Comment: I will get the error if i set foo.foo = new_foo(var)

Comment: @keywoker Yeah, that's not what the answer shows to do. You need to assign the function object, not the result of a call. Just add the variable to the definition.